# Angular2 has no exported mng error

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-cli

I have a lot of errors after updating an angular2 project from RC2 to Final 2.0.0

Most of them read: `has no exported mng 'such and such'`

Since I just got started with angular2 it would be great if someone could point me into a general direction/pattern on how to resolve such issues (generally, for debugging in the future etc)?

To name a few:

```
has no exported mng 'provideRouter'
has no exported mng 'RouterConfig'
has no exported mng 'ROUTER_DIRECTIVES'
has no exported mng 'addProviders'
```

Comment: Can you please add your package.json anda component that triggers this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seem to be errors from upgrading angular to the 2.0.0 version.

For each error you can look in the changelog of Angular github and find an answer there.

https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/d5515473bfd0974bacb0e7e5870e772426c9088d/CHANGELOG.md

For example: addProviders

```
 testing:
    withProviders, use TestBed.withModule instead
    addProviders, use TestBed.configureTestingModule instead
```